# Counting adjacent -1s in a 2d array without checking positions that are out of bounds (Minesweeper)

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am in the process of writing a program that works like Minesweeper. This is done in a 10x10 2d-array, and since I'm working with constraints, I can only write this using a 2d-array. However, I am getting a logical error with my `count()` method. The `count()` method returns the number of -1s found in the grid surrounding the input position (input position is what I'd make `row` and `column` in `main()`, for example, `(5, 5)`. It also must not check a position outside the bounds of the 2d array. [Here is a visual of what the output of `count()` should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DXVb.jpg)

I also have to use `count()` with `setCounts()`. `setCounts()` goes through the entire 2d array, skips any position that is a -1, and calls the `count()` method, setting the current position to the value the `count()` method returns.

```
    public int count(int row, int col)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
        {
            for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
            {
                if(c == 0 && r == 0)
                    continue;
                
                int newR = row + c;
                int newC = col + c;

                if(newR < 0 || newR >= array.length && newC < 0 || newC >= array[0].length)
                    continue;
    
                if(array[newR][newC] == -1)
                    value++;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setCounts()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
            {
                if(array[r][c] != -1)
                    array[r][c] = count(r, c);
                String formatted = String.format("%2d", array[r][c]);
                System.out.print(formatted + " ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that:

1. The `count()` method is incorrectly counting adjacent -1s surrounding any position I put in `main()`
2. `setCounts()` goes out of bounds after printing a random number of rows

I am certain that it has to do with this block of code:

```
if(newR < 0 || newR >= array.length && newC < 0 || newC >= array[0].length)
                    continue;
    
                if(array[newR][newC] == -1)
                    value++;
```

When I printed `newR` and `newC` in the loop after `continue`, the loop is randomly adding more numbers to a row/column combo with no direct pattern for the entire output when `count()` was called in `setCounts()`:

```
00
11
11
00
11
 0 01
12
12
01
12
 0 02
13
13
02
13
 0 03
14
14
03
14
 3 04
15
15
04
15
 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 09
09
 0 
-1 00
...
```

So taking the print statements out, I get this as an output:

```
0 -1 -1 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 
-1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 
0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
there are 0 -1s
-----------
 3  3  0 -1  3  3  0 -1  0  0 

/* Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10
    at Grid3.count(Grid3.java:44)
    at Grid3.setCounts(Grid3.java:58)
    at Grid3.main(Grid3.java:86) */
```

The first array is the array I make with `Grid`'s constructor. The second array that the program is trying to print is being done when `setCounts()` is called.

I was thinking that changing it to:

```
if(newR < 0 || newR >= array.length)
                    continue;
                    
                if(newC < 0 || newC >= array[0].length)
                    continue;
    
                if(array[newR][newC] == -1)
                    value++;
```

would work: and it does, but not logically. It gets rid of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error, but logically does not work since it doesn't count adjacent -1's right. It also seems to be adding more numbers randomly to any row/column combo. I put the position as `(5, 5)` in `main()` and one time I ran the code, it counted `6` -1s but there are only `3` -1s in the position I put:

```
-1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 -1 -1 0 0 -1 -1 0 
0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
-1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
there are 6 -1s
```

And for `setCounts()`, it printed a full 10x10 2d array but does not count -1s properly either. For the position `(0, 0)` (in this case, the `3` at the top left corner of the output shown below), that position should actually have a value of 2 since there are only 2 adjacent -1s, but it actually counts 3.

```
 3  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0 
-1 -1  0  3  0  0  0 -1  0  0 
-1  3  6  3 -1  0  3  0  3  0 
 0  3  0 -1 -1 -1  0 -1  0  0 
 3  0  0  0 -1  3  6  3  3  0 
 3 -1  0  0  0  3  0 -1 -1  0 
-1 -1  3  0  0  0  0  3  3  3 
 0  6  6  0  3  0  0  0 -1  0 
 0  0 -1 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  3 
 0  0  0  3  3  0  3  0  0  0
```

Here is a full output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 -1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 -1 -1 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 -1 0 
-1 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 -1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
there are 2 -1's
-----------
 3  0  0  3  0  0 -1  0  0  0 
 3 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  3  0  0 
 0 -1  6  3  0 -1  3  0  0  0 
 0  0 -1 -1 -1  3  3 -1  0  0 
 0  0  3  3  6 -1 -1  0 -1  0 
-1  0  0 -1  0 -1  3  6  0  3 
 3  3  0  0  3  0  3  3 -1  0 
 0 -1  0  0  0  3  0  3 -1  3 
 0  0  3  0  0  0 -1  0 -1  3 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  3
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I need `count()` to properly count adjacent -1s given a position. If it doesn't count adjacent -1s properly, then `setCounts()` will not logically work. What should I change in either or both methods so that it properly and logically works? Here is my code so far.

```
public class Grid
{
    private int [][] array;
    private int max;

    public Grid(int max)
    {
        array = new int[10][10];
        this.max = max;
        setRandom();
    }

    public void setRandom()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < max)
        {
            int r = (int)(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
            int c = (int)(Math.random() * 9) + 0;
            if(array[r][c] != -1)
                {
                    array[r][c] = -1;
                    i++;
                }
        }
    }

    public int count(int row, int col)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for(int r = -1; r < 2; r++)
        {
            for(int c = -1; c < 2; c++)
            {
                if(c == 0 && r == 0)
                    continue;
                
                int newR = row + c;
                int newC = col + c;

                if(newR < 0 || newR >= array.length && newC < 0 || newC >= array[0].length)
                    continue;
    
                if(array[newR][newC] == -1)
                    value++;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public void setCounts()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
            {
                if(array[r][c] != -1)
                    array[r][c] = count(r, c);
                String formatted = String.format("%2d", array[r][c]);
                System.out.print(formatted + " ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }   

    public void print()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[r][c] + " ");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)  // printing grid
    {
        Grid first = new Grid(20);
        int count = first.count(5, 5);
        first.print();
        System.out.println("there are " + count + " -1s");
        System.out.println("-----------");
        first.setCounts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to not use a 2d-array.
Or at least, you might want to store an object representing each cell rather than just an int. This way, you could implement the logic for figuring out the neighboring cells for a particular cell within the Cell-Class.

Here is an example (using a map instead of an array):

```
public class Grid {

  public final int width, height;
  private final Map<Coordinate, Cell> cells;

  public Grid(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.cells = IntStream.range(0, width).boxed()
            .flatMap(column ->
                    IntStream.range(0, height).boxed()
                            .map(row -> new Coordinate(row, column))
            )
            .map(Cell::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Cell::getCoordinate, Function.identity()));
  }

  public Cell get(int row, int col) {
    return this.cells.get(new Coordinate(row, col));
  }

  public class Cell {
    private final Coordinate coordinate;
    private final boolean isMine;

    public Cell(Coordinate coordinate, boolean isMine) {
        this.coordinate = coordinate;
        this.isMine = isMine;
    }

    public Cell(Coordinate coordinate) {
        this(coordinate, new Random().nextBoolean());
    }

    public Coordinate getCoordinate() {
        return coordinate;
    }

    public List<Cell> getNeighbours() {
        int leftNeighbourColumnIdx = coordinate.column - 1;
        int topNeighbourRowIdx = coordinate.row - 1;
        return IntStream.range(leftNeighbourColumnIdx, leftNeighbourColumnIdx + 3).boxed()
                .flatMap(column -> IntStream.range(topNeighbourRowIdx, topNeighbourRowIdx + 3).boxed().map(row -> new Coordinate(row, column)))
                .map(Grid.this.cells::get)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(c -> !c.equals(this))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public int countNeighbouringMines() {
        return (int) getNeighbours().stream()
                .filter(cell -> cell.isMine)
                .count();
    }
  }

  public static class Coordinate {
    private final int row, column;

    public Coordinate(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Coordinate that = (Coordinate) o;
        return row == that.row && column == that.column;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(row, column);
    }
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var grid = new Grid(10, 10);
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < grid.width; col++) {
            final var cell = grid.get(row, col);
            System.out.print(cell.isMine ? "x" : "o");
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.printf("mines around (5,5): %d%n", grid.get(5, 5).countNeighbouringMines());
  }
```

}

### Edit: same example as above but with a 2d-array instead of a map

```java
public class Grid {

    public final int width, height;
    private final Cell[][] cells;

    public Grid(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        cells = new Cell[width][height];

        IntStream.range(0, width)
                .forEach(column -> IntStream.range(0, height)
                        .forEach(row -> cells[column][row] = new Cell(column, row))
                );
    }

    public Cell get(int row, int col) {
        final var column = col < 0 || col >= this.cells.length ? null : this.cells[col];
        return row < 0 || column == null || row >= column.length ? null : column[row];
    }

    public class Cell {
        private final int column, row;
        private final boolean isMine;

        public Cell(int column, int row, boolean isMine) {
            this.column = column;
            this.row = row;
            this.isMine = isMine;
        }

        public Cell(int column, int row) {
            this(column, row, new Random().nextBoolean());
        }

        public List<Cell> getNeighbours() {
            int leftNeighbourColumnIdx = column - 1;
            int topNeighbourRowIdx = row - 1;
            return IntStream.range(leftNeighbourColumnIdx, leftNeighbourColumnIdx + 3).boxed()
                    .flatMap(column -> IntStream.range(topNeighbourRowIdx, topNeighbourRowIdx + 3).boxed()
                            .map(row -> Grid.this.get(row, column)))
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(c -> !c.equals(this))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public int countNeighbouringMines() {
            return (int) getNeighbours().stream()
                    .filter(cell -> cell.isMine)
                    .count();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var grid = new Grid(10, 10);
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid.width; col++) {
                final var cell = grid.get(row, col);
                System.out.print(cell.isMine ? "x" : "o");
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.printf("mines around (5,5): %d%n", grid.get(5, 5).countNeighbouringMines());
    }
}
```

The idea is, that the `get(int row, int col)` method in `Grid` returns either a `Cell` object or `null` if `row` or `cell` are invalid -- but it never fails (throws an exception).
Every cell can then use this method to try to get all its neighbours (`getNeighbours()`).
The cell doesn't need to worry, if the row/column it asks for is valid or not -- this will be handled by `get(int row, int col)`.
It just needs to filter out all `null` values (those coordinates were invalid) and itself.

With `getNeighbours()`, you have a list with all the neighboring cells. If you filter out all cells which have no mines - you get a list of neighbours with mines on them -- and then you just need to count them.

Comment: This looks great and I really appreciate your help, but I'm writing my program under constraints, so a 2d-array is the only way I can do it. Should've clarified this in the post, very sorry